# Where is a list of all possibilities of XmlSchemaExceptions throw in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

I want to create a translation for the most common exceptions throwed by XmlSchemaExceptions using XmlReader in C# .NET. Didn't find anything on the web yet and don't want to manually generate different ones.. Someone has this?

Here is the snippet that I want to retrieve all different exceptions it can throw:

```
 private void XmlValidation()
    {
        //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName);
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemaSet.Add(null, schemaFileName);
        notification.Clear();
        XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xrs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        xrs.Schemas = schemaSet;
        xrs.ValidationEventHandler += (o, s) => {
            string warn = s.Severity + ": " + s.Message;
            notification.Add(warn);
            //  Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s.Severity, s.Message);
        };
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(xdoc.CreateReader(), xrs))
        {
            while (xr.Read()) { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look in the MS documentation for the methods that are called and copy the Exceptions from the documentation.

Comment: @Igor I was looking on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception?view=net-5.0 but didn't find a way to get a list of them

Comment: All methods in the documentation list Exceptions that can be thrown. Go through the methods you are using/calling and copy them accordingly.

Comment: I posted the code above, the methods are XmlReader.Create and XNode.CreateReader... they don't list the different validation args possibilities...

Comment: If the documentation doesn't specify it then you won't be able to rely on anything anyone else would give you as at best it'd an implementation detail subject to change.  If you want to catch any possible exception you catch `Exception`, rather than trying to actually enumerate every possibility and hoping you did it right.

Comment: [XmlReader.Create(TextReader, XmlReaderSettings)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.create?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlReader_Create_System_IO_TextReader_System_Xml_XmlReaderSettings_) can throw `ArgumentNullException` based on the documentation. `XNode.CreateReader` can throw `NotSupportedException`. As mentioned by @Servy catching `System.Exception` would be a better choice depending on how you want the code to behave and what you are planning on recovering from.

Comment: I think I didn't be clear enough... The list I want is like this:
** The value of the 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd:LastTag' element does not equal its fixed value.**
** The 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd:SlowdownType' element is invalid - The value '-100' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:unsignedByte' - The string '-100' is not a valid Byte value.**
** The 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd:item' element is invalid - The value 'BDK   s' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The actual length is not equal to the specified length.**